# Constructing Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I came across this code recently but don't quite understand what's going on.

```
auto c = vector<int> {};
```

What is the vector constructor returning?

Then this code:

```
c = vector<int> {1,2,3,4,5 };
```

Is the second `c` at a different memory location to the initial `c`?

Is the destructor called when `c` is reinitialised?

I searched the internet but could not find any examples of the above code.

How is the above different to

```
vector<int> c {};
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Short answer: that's C++11

Comment: please use correct formatting, otherwise text in angle brackets won't show up properly

Comment: As for the difference between `auto c = vector<int> {};` and `vector<int> c{};`, see Herb Sutter's [Almost Always Auto](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) style.

Comment: Have you come across {} and initialiser lists before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'first c' is where the variable c (a vector of int) is defined.

```
auto c = vector<int> {};
```

The 'second c' is just re-assignment of the value of c.  It is not a new variable so the memory address of c does not change and the destructor of c is not called.

```
c = vector<int> {1,2,3,4,5 };
```

What actually happens is that vector {1,2,3,4,5 } creates a temporary object of type vector which is initialized from the initializer list with the values 1,2,3,4,5.  This temporary object is then passed to c's copy constructor (or in C++11) the move constructor, so that c replaces its current values (if any) with the values from the temporary object.

The destructor for c will not be called until it goes out of scope (for e.g. the function exits or the control block {} in which it was defined exits).

Answer (score 5):

"As jrd1 says, it's a C++11 feature.

The keyword `auto` basically means that you let the compiler "guess" the type of the variable.

So `c` is a regular `vector<int>`.

Comment: "Guess" is a bit harsh - if the type cannot be completely deduced, it won't compile :)

Comment: True, I'll put double-quotes as well. :)

Comment: I figured this was the core of the misunderstanding, the rest would follow from it.

But sure, other answers are more complete and the person who asked the question accepted one of them.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the vector constructor returning?

An empty `vector<int>`; and the compiler deduces the type of the variable `c` from that constructor call, meaning `c` will get the type `vector<int>`. `auto` basically just saves you from typing the variable type two times - it's given already in the constructor call anyway, you now don't have to type it in front of the variable name a second time, you can use `auto` instead.

> Is the second c at a different memory location to the initial c?

No, it is the same vector; but the values from another, temporary `vector<int>` (which holds the values 1,2,3,4 and 5) get assigned to `c` via `operator=`.
That means, the address of `c` itself (`&c`) won't be changed. However, the data it contains (e.g. the result of `c.data()`) can and probably will change.

> Is the destructor called when c is reinitialised?

Not `c`'s destructor. Only the one from the temporary.

Comment: To clarify the memory location bit: `&c` will not change, but `c.data()` probably will.

Answer (score 1):

The first and the last line are functionally equivalent.

For the assignment:

```
c = vector<int> {1,2,3,4,5 };
```

c will not be destructed or be afterwards located at a new memory operation.
What happens is that an unnamed second vector will be created with the 5 values, and the `vector::operator=` will be used to assign the content of that vector to c. This will happen in term of a move operation in C++11. Afterwards the temporary vector will be destroyed and it's destructor called, but not the destructor of c.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 includes the auto keyword which does **Type Inference** for you.
It helps to simplify code by a great deal.
Example:

```
auto itr = vec.iterator(); // instead of vector<int>::iterator itr
```